# jsx illustrator script - set radio option as default when the script loads

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

First time i ever play around with JSX files. This is an illustrator script i downloaded. I just want to edit it to set an option as default - i want the radio "size" checked by default when the script loads. I tried a couple of things but it didn't work and my knowledges are very limited :(

[image]

I want the radio "size" checked when the script loads, instead of "area"

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Select Paths By Size v.4.1.1.0 -- CS, CS2, CS3,CS4 (Change extension from 'jsx' to 'js' to run in CS)
//>=--------------------------------------
//   Selects all Path Objects, smaller/larger than given threshold
//   Only works for path and compound path objects.
//
//    If paths are selected, script runs on selected items only,
//    If nothing is selected, script runs on all paths in document.
//      ::: Updates in V2 :::
//      &bull; Rebuilt to select based on Size,  Area,  Width or by Height.
//      &bull; Added "same size as" option
//      &bull; If one object is selected, starts threshold at that size.
//      &bull; Added Tool Tips
//      ::: Updates in V3 :::
//      &bull; Added status indicator
//      &bull; Rebuilt processing engine so it's faster and more accurate
//      ::: Updates in V4 :::
//      &bull; Added  progress bar  (CS3 and above)
//      &bull; Speed increase
//      ::: Update v4.1 :::
//      &bull; Select by stroke weight (patched in 4.1.1)
//>=--------------------------------------
// JS code (c) copyright: John Wundes ( john@wundes.com ) www.wundes.com
//copyright full text here:  http://www.wundes.com/js4ai/copyright.txt
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

/*   Notes:

*/
 function Loadbar(x){
        this.versionNum= app.version.split(".")[0] ;
     if (this.versionNum >= 13){
        this.w = new Window('window', "Processing...", undefined, {independent:true});
        this.w.frameLocation = [600,500];
        this.w.tracker = this.w.add ('statictext' , [15,15,250,35], "processing");
        this.w.prog = this.w.add ('progressbar' , [15,15,250,35], 0, x);
        //this.w.show();
    }
 }

Loadbar.prototype.close = function(){
     if (this.versionNum >= 13){
            this.w.close();
     }
}
Loadbar.prototype.hide=function(){
     if (this.versionNum >= 13){
            this.w.hide();
     }
}
Loadbar.prototype.show=function(){
     if (this.versionNum >= 13){
            this.w.show();
     }
}
Loadbar.prototype.update=function(x){
     if (this.versionNum >= 13){
        this.w.prog.value = x; 
    }
}
Loadbar.prototype.label=function(x){
     if (this.versionNum >= 13){
        this.w.tracker.text = x; 
     }
}

if (app.documents.length > 0)
{
    var doc = app.activeDocument;

    var sel = doc.selection;
    var defaultValue = 10;
    var isStrokeSelected = false;
    if (sel.length == 1)
    {
        var seed =  (sel[0].width + sel[0].height) /2;
        if (seed != 0 || seed != null)
        {
            defaultValue = seed;
        }
    }

    var OK = 1;
    var by = "none";// flag for what method to walk objects selection/doc
    var tolerance = .005;
    var DISP_COLOR = new RGBColor();
          DISP_COLOR.red = 0;
          DISP_COLOR.green = 100;
          DISP_COLOR.blue = 0;


var myVersion = Math.floor(version.split(".")[0]);

if (myVersion == 12 || myVersion == 11)
{
    try{
    //if version is CS2
        var tVar = prompt("Enter the numeric threshold, use '>' for greater than and '<' for less than,\n i.e.; '>50' would mean 'greater than 50', to match exactly, just enter a number.","<"+defaultValue);// dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.slide.value;
        if (tVar == null)
        {
            OK=3;
            throw("end");
        }
        var tArr = tVar.split("");
        var threshold = tVar;
        var GT = false;
        var LT = false;
        var EQ = false;
        if (tArr[0] == "<")
        {
            LT =  true;
            threshold = tVar.substr(1);
        } else if (tArr[0] == ">")
        {
            GT =  true;
            threshold = tVar.substr(1);
        } else {
            EQ = true;
        } 
        var CP_on = confirm("Include compound path objects?");
        var includeLocked = confirm("Include locked objects?");
        var dVal = prompt("Enter method for comparison, ('s'=size,'w'=width,'h'=height,'a'=area,'k'=stroke)","s");
        if (dVal == null)
        {
            OK=3;
            throw("end");
        }       

        var dims = "size";
        if (dVal == "w")
        {
            dims = "width";
        } else if (dVal == "h")
        {
            dims = "height";
        }else if (dVal == "a")
        {
            dims = "area";
        }
        else if (dVal == "k")
        {
            dims = "strokeWidth";
             isStrokeSelected=true;
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        // use "OK" values instead... 
    }

} else if (myVersion > 12)
{
    //use advanced functionality
    //--------------------------Dialog Box Code --------------------------------------------------------
    var dlg = new Window('dialog', 'Select Path Items:'); 
    dlg.location = [500,50];
    //                                                                                                      [startX, StartY, EndX, EndY]
    dlg.alertBtnsPnl1 = dlg.add('group', undefined, 'Path Objects Size:');
    // Radio Buttons for Larger than, or smaller than
    (dlg.alertBtnsPnl1.selectLT = dlg.alertBtnsPnl1.add('radiobutton', [15,15,95,35], 'Smaller than' )).helpTip = "Select all  Path Items\nSmaller than\n the Slider Value."; 
    (dlg.alertBtnsPnl1.selectSS = dlg.alertBtnsPnl1.add('radiobutton', [15,15,75,35], 'Exactly' )).helpTip = "Select all Path Items\nThe Same value as\n the Slider Value."; 
    (dlg.alertBtnsPnl1.selectGT = dlg.alertBtnsPnl1.add('radiobutton', [15,15,95,35], 'Larger than' )).helpTip = "Select all Path Items\nLarger than \n the Slider Value."; 

    dlg.alertBtnsPnl1.selectLT.value = true; 
    dlg.alertBtnsPnl1.orientation='row';
    // Set Size of threshold
     dlg.alertBtnsPnl2 = dlg.add('group',undefined, 'Threshold:');
    (dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.slide = dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.add('slider', [25,15,165,39], 'Set size of threshold object:')).helpTip = "Use Slider to set a threshold value."; 
     dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.slide.value = defaultValue; 
    (dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.titleEt = dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.add('edittext', [100,15,160,35], dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.slide.value)).helpTip = "Enter a threshold value."; 
     dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.titleEt.text = roundOff(defaultValue); 
    (dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.titleSt = dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.add('statictext', [15,15,35,35], 'px')).helpTip = "Pixels."; 
     dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.orientation='row';


    (dlg.dimsPnl = dlg.add('panel', undefined, 'In:')).helpTip = "How paths will be compared"; 
    dlg.dimsPnl.orientation='row';
    (dlg.dimsPnl.selectS = dlg.dimsPnl.add('radiobutton', [15,15,65,35], 'Size' )).helpTip = "(Width * Height) / 2"; 
    (dlg.dimsPnl.selectA = dlg.dimsPnl.add('radiobutton', [15,15,65,35], 'Area' )).helpTip = "The Items (internal) Area Value.\n Note: Open paths have no area.";
    (dlg.dimsPnl.selectW = dlg.dimsPnl.add('radiobutton', [15,15,70,35], 'Width' )).helpTip = "Select by Width ONLY";
    (dlg.dimsPnl.selectH = dlg.dimsPnl.add('radiobutton', [15,15,65,35], 'Height' )).helpTip = "Select by Height ONLY";
    (dlg.dimsPnl.selectStroke = dlg.dimsPnl.add('radiobutton', [15,15,65,35], 'Stroke' )).helpTip = "Select by Stroke Width ONLY";
    dlg.dimsPnl.selectA.value = true; 

    dlg.dimsPnl.selectS.onClick= setTextS;
    dlg.dimsPnl.selectH.onClick= setTextH;
    dlg.dimsPnl.selectA.onClick= setTextA;
    dlg.dimsPnl.selectW.onClick= setTextW;
    dlg.dimsPnl.selectStroke.onClick= setTextStk;


    // Add a checkbox to control selection
    dlg.alertBtnsPnl3 = dlg.add('group', undefined, '');
    (dlg.hasBtnsCb = dlg.alertBtnsPnl3.add('checkbox', [25,25,235,39], 'Include Compound Path Items?')).helpTip=" Select items within compound paths too."; 
    (dlg.incLocked = dlg.alertBtnsPnl3.add('checkbox', [25,25,235,39], 'Include Locked Items?')).helpTip=" Note: This unlocks everything."; 
    dlg.hasBtnsCb.value = true; 
    dlg.incLocked.value = false; 
    dlg.alertBtnsPnl3.orientation='column';

    dlg.btnPnl = dlg.add('group', undefined, 'Do It!'); 
    dlg.btnPnl.orientation='row';
    dlg.btnPnl.buildBtn1= dlg.btnPnl.add('button',[15,15,115,35], 'Cancel', {name:'cancel'}); 
    dlg.btnPnl.buildBtn2 = dlg.btnPnl.add('button', [125,15,225,35], 'OK', {name:'ok'}); 
    dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.slide.onChange= sliderChanged;
    dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.titleEt.onChanging = eTextChanged;
    dlg.btnPnl.buildBtn1.onClick= actionCanceled;
    dlg.show();

        // Translate dialog here:
        var threshold =  1*(dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.titleEt.text);// dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.slide.value;
        var CP_on = dlg.hasBtnsCb.value; //false; // !  confirm("Ignore compound path objects?");
        var GT = dlg.alertBtnsPnl1.selectGT.value;
        var EQ =  dlg.alertBtnsPnl1.selectSS.value;
        var LT =  dlg.alertBtnsPnl1.selectLT.value;
        var includeLocked = dlg.incLocked.value;
        var dims = "size";
        if (dlg.dimsPnl.selectW.value)
        {
            dims = "width";
            isStrokeSelected=false;
        } else if (dlg.dimsPnl.selectH.value)
        {
            dims = "height";
            isStrokeSelected=false;
        }else if (dlg.dimsPnl.selectA.value)
        {
            dims = "area";
            isStrokeSelected=false;
        }else if (dlg.dimsPnl.selectStroke.value)
        {
            dims = "strokeWidth";
              isStrokeSelected=true;
        }
    }  else {
    OK = 2; // alert and close with "version" message
    }// end version check

    //--------------------------Main Code Section --------------------------------------------------------

    var dObj = new Date();
    var start = dObj.getTime();
    var niceTime = (dObj.getMonth( )+1)+"-"+dObj.getDay( )+"-"+dObj.getFullYear( ).toString().substr(2)+"_"+dObj.getHours( )+"."+dObj.getMinutes( )+"."+dObj.getSeconds( );
    var topLocked = doc.layers[0].locked;
        if(OK==1){
            //add a temporary layer for tracking
            /*  //too slow
            var dispLayer = doc.layers.add();
            var pointTextRef = dispLayer.textFrames.add();
            pointTextRef.textRange.fillColor = DISP_COLOR;
            pointTextRef.selected = false;
            pointTextRef.top = doc.height/2;
            pointTextRef.left = doc.width/2;
            */
            var selItems = new Array();
            //pointTextRef.contents = "Pre-Processing!!!";
            //redraw();

            var selLen = sel.length;
            if(selLen >1){

                by = "selection";
                //
                var b = new Loadbar(selLen);
                b.label("Preprocessing Data...");
                b.show();
                // pointTextRef.top = selection[0].top;
                // pointTextRef.left =selection[0].left;
                // redraw();
            // deselect Compound path items if not included
                var cpLen = doc.compoundPathItems.length;
                for (var cp=0;cp<cpLen ;cp++ )
                {
                    b.label("Deselecting Compound Pathitem "+cp+" of "+cpLen);
                    b.update(cp);
                    if(!CP_on){
                        doc.compoundPathItems[cp].selected = false;
                    }
                }
            var plen = doc.pathItems.length;
            // Add selected path items to Array

                 var i = null;
                 for (var x=0;x<plen ;x++ )
                 {
                    b.label("Pre-Processing item "+x+" of "+plen);
                    b.update(x);
                     i = doc.pathItems[x];
                    if (i.selected== true   )
                    {
                        selItems.push(i);
                    }
                 }

            } else {
                by = "doc";
                //

                // copy pathitems array to selItems
                // if they arent part of a compoundPath

                var plen = doc.pathItems.length;
                var b = new Loadbar(plen);
                b.label("Preprocessing Data...");
                b.show();
                // Add selected path items to Array
                 var i = null;
                 for (var x=0;x<plen ;x++ )
                 {
                     i = doc.pathItems[x];
                    if (!CP_on && i.parent.typename == "CompoundPathItem")
                    {
                        continue;
                    }else if (!includeLocked && (i.layer.locked == true || i.locked==true))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }   else {
                        selItems.push(i);
                    } // end 'if'

                } // end 'for'

            } // end else

             if (myVersion <= 12 && selItems.length > 1000)
            {
                alert(" Go get a coffee, this is going to take a while...");
            }
            selectBelow(selItems);


            // -----------------cleanup and analytics--------------------------
             //pointTextRef.remove();
             // redraw();
            b.close();
            var fObj = new Date();
            var finish= fObj.getTime();
            var totalSeconds = (finish-start)/1000;
            var minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds/60); 
            var seconds = totalSeconds%60;
            alert(doc.selection.length+" Paths Selected in "+minutes+" minutes, "+Math.round(seconds)+" seconds.");
            //dispLayer.remove();
        } // end cancel test
} else {
    if (OK==2)
    {
        alert("You must have at least Illustrator CS to run this script!");
    } else if(OK ==3){
            //die quitly

    }

    else {
     alert("You must have a document open to run this script!");

    }

}

//----------------------------------------------Nobody here but us functions---------------------------------------------------------

//-------------------------------Dialog box functions---------------------------v.13 >
function actionCanceled() { 
    OK = 3;
    dlg.hide();
}
function sliderChanged() { 
    dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.titleEt.text = dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.slide.value;
}

function setTextS() { 
    //if single item selected, change default to items Size
    if (doc.selection.length == 1)
    {
        dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.titleEt.text = roundOff(Math.abs( (doc.selection[0].width+doc.selection[0].height)/2));
        isStrokeSelected=false;
    }

}
function setTextStk() { 
    //if single item selected, change default to items Stroke
    if (doc.selection.length == 1)
    {
        dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.titleEt.text = roundOff(doc.selection[0].strokeWidth);
        isStrokeSelected=true;
    }

}
function setTextH() { 
    //if single item selected, change default to items Height
        if (doc.selection.length == 1)
    {
        dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.titleEt.text = roundOff(doc.selection[0].height);
        isStrokeSelected=false;
    }
}
function setTextA() { 
    //if single item selected, change default to items Area
        if (doc.selection.length == 1)
    {
        dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.titleEt.text = roundOff(Math.abs( doc.selection[0].area));
        isStrokeSelected=false;
    }
}
function setTextW() { 
    //if single item selected, change default to items Width
        if (doc.selection.length == 1)
    {
        dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.titleEt.text = roundOff(doc.selection[0].width);
        isStrokeSelected=false;
    }
}
function eTextChanged() { 
    dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.slide.value = dlg.alertBtnsPnl2.titleEt.text;
}
//-------------------------------End Dialog box functions---------------------------v.13 >
// common functionality: 

 function selectBelow(sel){
    var MAX = sel.length;
     for (var x=0;x<MAX;x++)
     {
        // alert("now processing:"+sel[x].typename);
        if(sel[x].locked == true){
            if (includeLocked)
            {
                sel[x].locked = false;
            } else {
                continue;
            }

        }
        try{
            sel[x].selected = true;
        }
        catch(e){
            // on a locked layer...
        }

        //=========normal pathitem=============
        if (sel[x].typename == "PathItem")
        {            
                //pointTextRef.top = sel[x].top;
                //pointTextRef.left = sel[x].left;
                //pointTextRef.contents = "Processing item "+x+" of "+MAX;
                     if (myVersion <= 12){redraw();}
                //redraw();
                b.label("Processing item "+x+" of "+MAX);
                b.update(x);
                b.show();
                checkThreshold(sel[x],dims);

        }  else {

            //not a pathitem, dont care...
            sel[x].selected = false;
        }
    }
 }

 function checkThreshold(obj,prop){

    //alert(isStrokeSelected);
    //if stroke selected, and object not stroked, kill it
    if( ( isStrokeSelected  &&  ( obj.stroked == false) )){
        obj.selected=false;
        return;
    } 

     //if compound path kill it
     if(  CP_on == false && obj.parent.typename == "CompoundPathItem"){
            obj.selected=false;
            return;
     }

    var p = 0;
     if(prop == "size"){
         //square root of area...  (Need abs because in compound shapes, the area can be negative
          p = Math.abs( (obj.width+obj.height)/2);
     } else {
         p = Math.abs(eval("obj."+prop));
     }

    // deselect if less than
    if (GT && p < threshold+tolerance) // actually creating a tolerance for DEselection, meaning objects same size will be booted.
    {
        obj.selected=false;
        return;
    }
     // deselect if larger than
    if (LT && p > threshold-tolerance)
    {
        obj.selected=false;
        return;
    }
     // deselect if exactly same size as:
    if (EQ && (p<threshold-tolerance || p > threshold+tolerance) )
    {

        obj.selected=false;
        return;
    }
 }

 function copyArr(a){
 var a2 = [];
 var len = a.length;
for (var ca=0; ca<len;ca++ )
{
    a2.push(a[ca]);
}

 return a2;
 }
 function roundOff(x){
    var place = 100;
    x = Math.round(x*place);
    x /= place;
    return x;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

change the line:

```
dlg.dimsPnl.selectA.value = true;
```

to:

```
dlg.dimsPnl.selectS.value = true;
```